# Dynamically adding a web user control to a web user control (asp.net vb)

Tags: c#-to-vb.net, webusercontrol, web-user-controls

I need to convert a C# web site to VB. There is a page that loads a custom web control (WholeLife.ascx) and then within this control, could possibly load multiple web user controls dynamically (WholeLifeChild.ascx).
The C# version works, the VB version just cannot seem to recognize the controls (WholeLifeChild.ascx) that it neess to load within the main control (WholeLife.ascx).

C# Version (works):

```
private WholeLifeChild _selectedChild;
```

// Later, looping with a foreach creates loads multiple childChoice:

```
WholeLifeChilds childChoice = (WholeLifeChilds)LoadControl("~/Controls/WholeLifeChild.ascx");
phChildChoices.Controls.Add(childChoice);
childChoice.ID = "ChildChoices-" + appRate.DependentID;
childChoice.Initialize(appRate, _WholeLifeCoverage);
childChoice.ChildChoicesChanged += new WholeLifeChild.ChangingHandler(ChildChoices_Changed);
```

VB Version (cannot find custom web user control):

```
Private _selectedChild As WholeLifeChild **(vb complains here on WholeLifeChild)**
```

'Later, looping with a foreach creates loads multiple childChoice:
(VB complains on the **WholeLifeChild** as if it cannot locate it)

```
Dim childChoice As WholeLifeChild = DirectCast(LoadControl("~/UserControls/WholeLifeChild.ascx"), WholeLifeChild)
phChildChoices.Controls.Add(childChoice)
childChoice.ID = "ChildChoices-" + appRate.DependentID
childChoice.Initialize(appRate, _WholeLifeCoverage)
childChoice.ChildChoicesChanged += New WholeLifeChild.ChangingHandler(AddressOf ChildChoices_Changed)
```

'This VB Version cannot find the WholeLifeChild.ascx control which is in the same directory as the control it's loading to (WholeLife.ascx).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you still having issues with this?  Can you post your page declarations?

Comment: Hi Grim, thanks, but I did figure out how to get it working in VB.net, thanks! Is there a way to "close" out questions so others know it's been solved?

Comment: Yes, I believe the protocol is to add the answer yourself.